# Where to find information on http://www.alibaba.com api in english?

Tags: java, web-services, integration

I would like to search, check new RFQ, and offers on http://www.alibaba.com in my application. I was looking for API but I cannot find any information about it. I wonder how such an integration could be implemented. I suppose that there must be some paid service.

Of course, the brute force approach would be to a browser automation with e.g., [Watir](http://watir.com/).

UPDATE: 
I have found some information but in chinese: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&sl=auto&tl=en&twu=1&u=http://www.alisoft.com/home/index.html

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to use it .. 
There's a sort page in aliexpress and i couldn't understand how to use the API .

http://portals.aliexpress.com/help/help_center_API.html

Comment: eran, have you registered as a developer?

Answer (score 2):

The API isn't in English but if you use Google Chrome, you can right click and select translate to English. It does the trick for about 80 to 85% of the page!

Comment: To date it seems like a best approach.